# Need help in array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays

Code Language : PHP

Actually i am not expert in array manipulation 
I have tried too much but didn't get success. 
Please check following array i want convert it.

I have this type of array

```
 [
      {
        "user_id": "1",
        "name": "A",
        "product": "Product A",
        "price": "456"
      },
      {
        "user_id": "1",
        "name": "A",
        "product": "Product B",
        "price": "255"
      },
      {
        "user_id": "1",
        "name": "A",
        "product": "Product C",
        "price": "111"
      },
      {
        "user_id": "2",
        "name": "B",
        "product": "Product D",
        "price": "888"
      },
      {
        "user_id": "2",
        "name": "B",
        "product": "Product E",
        "price": "408"
      }
    ]
```

I want to convert it to following

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "product_data": [
      {
        "product": "Product A",
        "price": "456"
      },
      {
        "product": "Product B",
        "price": "255"
      },
      {
        "product": "Product C",
        "price": "111"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "B",
    "product_data": [
      {
        "product": "Product D",
        "price": "888"
      },
      {
        "product": "Product E",
        "price": "408"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please help me to solve out this..

Comment: You can convert that to a PHP array using `json_decode()`, and from there you can run a `foreach()` loop over it, to help you build the output array. Would you give that a try? We are not a code-on-demand service here. Your solution does not have to be finished - we just want to see some effort.

Comment: Not only that we want to _see_ some effort. We want to work from there and fix or finish it.

Comment: Vivek, please give structure in PHP object not in JS object

Comment: You just need to convert it to array... you will get php array... Here php array is not written.... 

Its written in json for better understand the Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by foreach() and array_key_exists() functions. Please see the below code, it may help you:

```
<?php

  $json ='[{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "product": "Product A",
    "price": "456"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "product": "Product B",
    "price": "255"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "product": "Product C",
    "price": "111"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "B",
    "product": "Product D",
    "price": "888"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "B",
    "product": "Product E",
    "price": "408"
  }]';
  $source_array = json_decode($json);
  $result_arry = array();
  foreach($source_array as $entry)
  {
      if(array_key_exists($entry->user_id,$result_arry))
      {
                      $result_arry[$entry->user_id]['product_data'][] = array('product' => $entry->product,'price'=>$entry->price);
      }
      else
      {

        $result_arry[$entry->user_id] = array('user_id' =>$entry->user_id,'name'=>$entry->name,'product_data'=>array());
        $result_arry[$entry->user_id]['product_data'][] = array('product' => $entry->product,'price'=>$entry->price);
      }

  }
  print_r($result_arry);
```